# iOS8 how to selectively modify a single constraint programmatically leaving all others intact?

Tags: ios, uiview, ios8, autolayout, size-classes

I've seen a number of implementations of side panels that can be dragged on/off screen using calculations of position. This approach seems to be very fragile with autolayout and size classes, especially after device rotates or interface changes size class.

I'm looking to implement the drag on/off screen behavior for a single panel that has been defined in a storyboard (all constraints defined). **How do I programmatically add or modify a single constraint for this panel to implement panel moving behavior in X directio?** I want to leave all other constraints intact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a horizontal constraint to the left edge of the super view, and make an IBOutlet to that constraint. You can then modify its constant property in code to move the panel. If you set the constant to  -sidePanel.frame.size.width it will be just off the screen to the left.